# Virtual Box in Ubuntu host machine - NAT network not working

Tags: networking, virtualbox, nat

I'm trying to get some virtual machines running in Virtual Box and I want to use the "NAT network" network setting, but I can't get internet connection to work.  Is there some setting I need to adjust in the host Ubuntu machine?

Comment: hi, how did you connect to network? using wifi or ethernet?

Comment: Please post the output of `ping 8.8.8.8` and `ping www.google.com`. from both the host machine, and the guest machine.

Comment: You probably need to use the `bridged` network setting for your VB VM.